# openbravo 3.0 erp - Can any one have source code link of openbravo

Tags: openbravo

I want to do setup of Openbravo in my local . I want java source code link and all required information for set up . Please guide/Help me .

Answer (score 0):

Anand,
I'm not sure whether OpenBravo has been willing to share their source. The project has been around awhile. Perhaps an older version is available. Try sourceforge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/openbravo/files/?source=navbar

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link [Setup_Eclipse_Openbravo](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/How_to_setup_Eclipse_IDE/) to setup locally.
The source can be cloned using the below command.

```
hg clone https://code.openbravo.com/erp/devel/main openbravo
```

Note: You should have a look at the [Development Stack](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Development_Stack_Setup) first.

Answer (score 0):

please use the git command

#git clone https://gitlab.com/openbravo/product/openbravo

or Download from https://gitlab.com/openbravo/product/openbravo